# Is it possible to retrieve the phone numbers of both the dual sim cards in Android programmatically.

Tags: android, telephonymanager, sim-card

I did refer to one of the [answers](http://foo.com) suggested before and edited it because the sim index is not checked in that answer. Here's what I used.

```
SubscriptionManager subscriptionManager = SubscriptionManager.from(getApplicationContext());
        List<SubscriptionInfo> subsInfoList = subscriptionManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoList();



        for (SubscriptionInfo subscriptionInfo : subsInfoList) {
            Log.d("Test", "Current list = " + subscriptionInfo);
            Integer index=subscriptionInfo.getSimSlotIndex();
            if(index==1)
            {
                Log.d("Test", " Number is  " + subscriptionInfo.getNumber());
            }
            else
                Log.d("Test", " Number is  " + subscriptionInfo.getNumber());
        }
```

But I'm unable to get the number of the sim used in slot 1, only the number of sim in index 0 is received.

Here's the logcat

```
Current list = {id=2, iccId=89918620400015502403 simSlotIndex=0 displayName=Jio 4G 01 carrierName=Jio 4G nameSource=0 iconTint=-16746133 dataRoaming=1 iconBitmap=android.graphics.Bitmap@6443203 mcc 405 mnc 862}
D/Test:  Number is  1234567//It's a made up number. I did get my actual number
D/Test: Current list = {id=3, iccId=89919509129941235317 simSlotIndex=1 displayName=airtel 02 carrierName=airtel nameSource=0 iconTint=-13408298 dataRoaming=1 iconBitmap=android.graphics.Bitmap@3986580 mcc 404 mnc 95}
D/Test:  Number is
```

As seen in logcat, I cannot get the number for the sim in slotindex 1. Many other details of the 2nd sim can be retrieved including displayname, carriername etc. But the subscriptionInfo.getNumber(), works only for one sim.

Comment: Check my comment on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43233795/how-to-detect-the-changed-sim-card-details-in-a-phone-which-has-dual-sim-card-sl#comment73537738_43233795) question.

Comment: Yes, I saw the documentation on SubscriptionManager, I have posted it in this question itself.  I have said in the question that unlike TelephonyManager, there are no methods to get phone number, sim serial number etc. I have checked in the documentation. I got the methods for TelephonyManager from [https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html]       I'm unable to find similar methods in SubscriptionManager.

Comment: @AishwaryaTiwari I have updated the code I used. Please check